# deselecting UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm calling a view controller from a table view. When I return back the caller view the table cell that I pressed before stays selected so that I couldn't select it again before  selecting another cell.

I've added deselectRowAtIndexPath method like below but it didn't worked.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *ctrl = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"node"];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ctrl animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` is only called AFTER your row has already been deselected, so your call to `deselectRowAtIndexPath` is useless. Simply place this in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to deselect it after tapping on it:

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `UITableViewController` there is a property for that. You can set it in you `-viewDidLoad` method of your `UITableViewController` subclass:

```
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;
```

Otherwise you have to do it manually. Just deselect it in `-viewWillAppear:`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];
}
```

The method you have shown is not necessary for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are committing an error on the `delegate method`. When you **select a row** in a `tableView`, is called:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

So your code should be in this method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *ctrl = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"node"];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ctrl animated:YES];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

So now that you call `deselectRowAtIndexPath` is called also:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

But in your case, you don't need to implement something in this method.